# How to install/load iptables “rpfilter” module in a bash script?

Tags: iptables

Platform: Asuswrt-Merlin using kernel 2.6.36

How do you install/load the iptables "rpfilter" module in a bash script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know that netfilter module is not supported on kernels 2.6.x. The support was added starting with kernel 3.x

Please check the link bellow:
https://www.snbforums.com/threads/how-to-load-iptables-rpfilter-module.39842/

Comment: Does that mean setting values in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter isn't support either ? If it is supported, what is the difference between this method and using the netfilter module ?